# Fatal Error After adding facebook dependencies

Tags: android, dependencies, facebook-login

In my application I added the following dependencies to begin work around facebook API a little latter in my code.

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
```

But as I added these dependencies and no other thing in my application code.my application started crashing on startup.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.facebook.accountkit.internal.AccountKitInitProvider: 500: 
Initialization error: 503: 
The Client Token must be specified in the string resource file as com.facebook.accountkit.ClientToken

       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4911)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4503)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4443)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1268)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: 500: Initialization error: 503: The Client Token must be specified in the string resource file as com.facebook.accountkit.ClientToken
       at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.Initializer.getRequiredString(Initializer.java:225)
       at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.Initializer.initialize(Initializer.java:115)
       at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.AccountKitController.initialize(AccountKitController.java:540)
       at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.AccountKitInitProvider.onCreate(AccountKitInitProvider.java:31)
       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1616)
       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1587)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4908)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4503) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4443) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1268) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

**EDITED:**
I have also added in Menifest latter

```
<provider
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
    android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider******"
    android:exported="true" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/fbAppId" />
```

And in my Application class

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();

     FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
     if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
         FacebookSdk.setIsDebugEnabled(true);
         FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
     }
 }
```

But Still its crashing Don't know where this error comes from? However as I remove these dependencies my code runs fine.

Comment: this error is not caused by the dependencies. error is in this line `android:value="@string/fbAppId"`. maybe you are not using Facebook api key that you generated for  your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Client Token must be specified in the string resource file as com.facebook.accountkit.ClientToken

It clearly says you must have `com.facebook.accountkit.ClientToken` and its token in manifest file

Add

```
<meta-data 
    android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ClientToken"
    android:value="@string/ACCOUNT_KIT_CLIENT_TOKEN" />
```

in your Menifest file.

for more information please visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android

Comment: uh I saw it in documentation right now but it was working fine a day ago actually I added these dependencies long ago about 2 and a half month ago app was running  fine but it suddenly started crashing.

Comment: That is fascinating. well try adding this tag and see if it works. I am sure you got ACCOUNT_KIT_CLIENT_TOKEN tho.

Comment: it worked you saved my day Thanks :) But a day before it as running cool. I thought I may have missed somethind